# git commit doesn't appear to work when --porcelain option is set

Tags: git

It appears that `git commit` doesn't work when the `--porcelain` option is selected. Is this a bug? Or am I misunderstanding something about how `git commit` works?

I have a repo containing one file that has been modified.  When I run `git status`, I see this (as expected):

```
On branch main
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/main'.

Changes to be committed:
  (use "git restore --staged <file>..." to unstage)
    modified:   README.md
```

When I run `git commit -m "Update to readme" --porcelain` I get this output:

```
$ git commit -m "Update to readme" --porcelain
M  README.md
```

But, when I run `git status` again, I get the original output:

```
On branch main
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/main'.

Changes to be committed:
  (use "git restore --staged <file>..." to unstage)
    modified:   README.md
```

Now, if I commit without `--porcelain` I get the expected behaivor:

```
[main 6f17cac] Update to readme
 1 file changed, 6 insertions(+), 3 deletions(-)
```

And `git status` also gives the expected result:

```
On branch main
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/main' by 1 commit.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)

nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

Is this a bug? Or am I misunderstanding something about how `git commit` works?

I am using git 2.37.1 on MacOS 12.6:

```
$ git --version
git version 2.37.1 (Apple Git-137.1)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`--porcelain` implies `--dry-run` which does not actually do the commit.

> --dry-run
>
> ***Do not create a commit***, but show a list of paths that are to be committed, paths with local changes that will be left uncommitted and paths that are untracked.

> --porcelain
>
> When doing a dry-run, give the output in a porcelain-ready format. See git-status(1) for details. ***Implies --dry-run***.